# Bluetooth Low Energy get characteristic description

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have one bluetooth 4.0 sensor which send me many services and characteristics, like this draft example:

```
<service uuid="ServiceUUID" advertise="true">
  <description>Test Service</description>
     <characteristic uuid="CharacteristUUID" id="test_rate">
         <properties read="true" notify = "true"/>
            <value length="1" type="hex"></value>
            <description>Test Rate</description>
     </characteristic>
</service>
```

I start with android sample BluetoothLEGatt and I want get the characteristic description name for example (Test Rate) dynamically, because in sample they use SampleGattAttributes class to get the description programmatically.

Anyone know how it is possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

For BluetoothGatt dynamic data you have to follow below steps to create the call back methods

1. Create object of Bluetooth Device, device Address will be the one which you will get after connection

   ```
    BluetoothManager m = (BluetoothManager)context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
           m_adapter = m.getAdapter();
   BluetoothDevice device = m_adapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
   ```
2. Create BluetoothGatt object

   ```
       private BluetoothGatt m_gatt;
       m_gatt = m_device.connectGatt(m_context, false, m_callback);
   ```

   3.Call back implementation

   ```
     private final BluetoothGattCallback m_callback = new BluetoothGattCallback()
    {        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
       String testid = characteristic.getDescriptor(characteristic.getUuid()).getCharacteristic().getStringValue(0);
   };
                   }
   ```

Make sure for the bluetooth permission and other minor variable declaration.

Comment: First thanks for you time, but i get the data correctly, i want get the text inside of tags <description></description>, in other words "Test Rate", dynamically to show the user without previous declare in my code that description UUID is "Test Rate".

Comment: are you talking about parsing the XML file? which you are received?

Comment: in my code, i want do something like gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor( gattCharacteristic.getUuid()).getDescription(); to get Test Rate string from object directly. I not certainty if i receive from sensor xml...

Comment: Edited the ans,please have a look and let me know